# NetworkStream BeginRead / EndRead

Tags: c#, winforms, tcp, tcpclient

I'm really new to C# programming and I'm developing an application based on a TcpClient.

I would like to know how to use BeginRead & EndRead, I've already read MSN documentation but doesn't help.

I've this :

> ```
>     private void Send()
>     {
>         TcpClient _client = new TcpClient("host", 80);
>         NetworkStream ns = _client.GetStream();
>         ns.Flush();
>         / ...
>         ns.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
>
>         int BUFFER_SIZE = 1024;
>         byte[] received = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
>         ns.BeginRead(received, 0, 0, new AsyncCallback(OnBeginRead), ns);
>     }
>
>     private void OnBeginRead(IAsyncResult ar)
>     {
>         NetworkStream ns = (NetworkStream)ar.AsyncState;
>         int BUFFER_SIZE = 1024;
>         byte[] received = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
>         string result = String.Empty;
>
>         ns.EndRead(ar);
>
>         int read;
>         while (ns.DataAvailable)
>         {
>             read = ns.Read(received, 0, BUFFER_SIZE);
>             result += Encoding.ASCII.GetString(received);
>             received = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
>         }
>         result = result.Trim(new char[] { '\0' });
>         // Want to update Form here with result
>     }
> ```

How can I update a Form component using result ?

Thanks for help.

Comment: I had a same problem here and I wanted to know if it's OK to rise an event right at where you inserted a comment line for updating the Form. subscribe to the event from Form and update what it? or is it in separate thread and will cause some problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I recommend learning a lot about multithreading. Then come back and learn about sockets. Both of these have rather steep learning curves, and trying to tackle both is a *lot* to handle.

That said, you can post an update to the UI by capturing the UI context via `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext` and scheduling a `Task` to that `TaskScheduler`. If the TPL isn't available, then you can just use `SynchronizationContext` directly.

Comment: I've read more about SynchronizationContext and works perfectly, thanks ! Will read more about both, thanks :)